# What is the name for?

Tags: python, terminology

I was just wondering, what is the terminology used for bits of code such as:

```
.lower()
.upper()
.get()
len()
```

And just general commands such as that.

Comment: I think it's best if you go through some of https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ or http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ or http://www.diveintopython.net/ before posting

Comment: I understand what they are, I was just wondering the are called. Don't perceive my question as ignorance :P

Comment: All but the last one is a special type of function called a ["method"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29) of an object. Almost everything in Python is an object: strings, sets, numbers, functions, etc. [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=len#len) on the other hand is the name of one of the many functions built-in or included with the language, many of which be called with arguments of a number of different types and aren't associated with just one class or class hierarchy of object types.

Comment: Python is concise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms `.lower()`, `.upper()`, `.get()` etc are called methods in python.

these are functions which are members of a Class.

In a technical way,

A method is a function that takes a class instance as its first parameter. Methods are members of classes.

```
class My_Class:
    def method(self, possibly, other, arguments):
        pass # do something here
```

**EDIT**

thanks for @J.F.Sebastian for pointing it out,

`len()` is a function, not a method. `len()`, `dir()`, `int()`, `open()`, `sorted()` etc. are built -in functions of python.

**Even more edit for conceptual clarification**

Generally speaking, methods are functions that belong to a class, functions can be on any  scope of the code. So in normal words you can say that all methods are functions, but not all functions are methods. Easy way to distinguish between both is the `.` operator. If it is preceded by a `.` operator it is a method. The general calling of a method is `the_instance.the_method()`

Comment: @Dinar: `len()` is not a method. It is a built-in function.

Comment: I don't agree with your last sentence: "The general calling of a method is `the_parent_class.the_method()`." While `the_parent_class` is surely a valid name for an instance, you'd better say `the_instance.the_method()`. Method calls on classes are usually made only with class methods and static methods.

Answer (score 2):

Those are "functions."  The ones that are used with an "instance" like `"blah".upper()` are often called "methods" (of a class).

Comment: Oh right, aha. I got totally confused with the terminology thanks for clearing it up! :)